# making all checkboxes in same vertical column

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to make all my checkboxes in the same vertical column in my XML file of the android project.
The result and code is given;

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cannamon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cinnamon"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/nutmeg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nutmeg"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/nutella"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nutella"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/whipped_cream"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Whipped Cream"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I think the constraints of the linear layout are correct.
Or should I use the Grid layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of ways to do it. Here's an example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="left">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cannamon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cinnamon"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/nutmeg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nutmeg"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/nutella"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nutella"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/whipped_cream"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Whipped Cream"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use ConstraintLayout. I think you wanted to achieve something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="CheckBox"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="CheckBoxTest"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is aligning the center of each CheckBox view to the center. Since each CheckBox is not the same width, the boxes will not line up. What you can do is align everything to the left, then wrap this LinearLayout in another which centers it. Here is an example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cannamon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cinnamon"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/nutmeg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nutmeg"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/nutella"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nutella"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/whipped_cream"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Whipped Cream"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:gravity="center" from linearlayout from your xml code

Comment: This would result in the CheckBoxes being all the way to the left, but I think OP still wants the them in the center, but with the boxes aligned.